# Type casting an integer to a function argument of type object

Tags: c++, function, casting, overloading, operator-keyword

I am currently working on an assignment where one of the goals is to be able to write:

```
v1 = v2 + v3;
v1 = v2 + 7;
v1 = 7 + v3;
```

All with a single overloaded operator+.
I got the tip that there was casting involved.

How do you cast and integer to an object that uses that integer to do something?

```
Verzameling operator+(const Verzameling& vl, const Verzameling& vr){
    //I know this code is not functional. The inmportant part here is the 
    //arguments of the operator+ function
    Verzameling verzameling;
    return verzameling;
}
```

To get an idea of what I want to happen:
The goal of the project is to make an object which is in essence A list.
An array with dynamic memory. That part works completely.

Though when the + operator is called on these objects, it needs to return the union of these 2 lists.
When something is written like:
    v1 = 2 + v3;
It means to create a list with size 1 and contents the number 2.
Then make the union of that newly created list and list v3.

```
v1 = v2 + 7;
```

The only difference here is that the created list with size 1 and contents 7 will be appended to the list of v2 instead of inserted before like the one above.

The constructor(int i) of the object also accepts an int but its job is to make an array of size i. Wheras when an int is passed to the operator+ it should create an object with array size 1 and with the value of the int in that spot.

This is easy to do with 3 separate operator+ overloads, however the question is to do it with 1. I am at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you write operator + which concatinates your lists, and constructor for you type which can accept int, and so you should have all 3 use case of operator work the way you described

Comment: The thing is, and I am gonna put this in my original question too, when an int is passed to the + operator it doesn't have the same job as the regular constructor does. the job of the constructor(int i) is to initialize the array with i spots. The integer that is being passed to the + operator has as function to create an array and put the value inside.

Comment: short version - modify your constructor, long version -you have problem, possible solution and existing code, that prevents using of solution. The question is: what does have more importance for you, solving the problem, or avoiding modification of preexisting code?

Comment: How could I modify my constructor to make this work?

Comment: For it to work constructor that takes single int should counstruct single element list containing argument

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. The default constructor's job takes an int i and has the job of creating an array with i empty spots. However the second constructor I need also needs to take an int j, and it's job is to make an array with 1 spot and the value of j stored in that spot.